Ubuntu 24.04 is killing itself after proper nvidia drivers installation (it is installing recommended ubuntu drivers alongside with proper drivers)
Ubuntu 24.04 is killing itself after proper nvidia drivers installation (it is installing recommended ubuntu drivers alongside with proper drivers, even if I blocked the installation of recommended drivers). Please, help. I'm installing this piece of "ART" for the fourth time this week. Or just recommend a normal Linux distro which doesn't have ubuntu restrictions.
Why nvidia drivers from the website is the proper choice? Because they use directory where the other software looks for the drivers and you don't really need to manually set up you environment, which will crash after the update. That's why it could be better to cut off nvidia drivers from ubuntu, because their easy to install approach leads to "not at all easy to install".

You should only use the recommended drivers that come with Ubuntu, not the NVIDIA upstream latest drivers.  The NVIDIA drivers that ship in Ubuntu and the kernel are optimized to properly work with supported hardware, etc. I would suggest you remove the manually installed nvidia drivers (assuming "proper" means you've installed the binary .run from NVIDIA) and rely on what's tested and properly released in the repositories. There usually is NOT a need to use the absolute latest and greatest drivers within Ubuntu.

I don't use latest drivers, just 550 with cuda 12.4. And they worked great until OS decided to kill itself.

Except that's in the Ubuntu repositories.  What do you mean my "proper nvidia drivers" then?  Note also you need to provide these details in your question, and less word this like a rant (your last two lines turn this into a rant not a question)

I don't really care). Proper nvidia drivers from Nvidia website.

that's the "latest drivers" then from NVIDIA.  Which are not designed with optimizations to work in Ubuntu. Debian has the same problem as do othoer distros which have to ship nonfree drivers optimized for their kernels.  Is there a reason you don't just install nvidia-driver-550 which is the same but properly built for the Ubuntu environment instead of relying on the "separately installed" drivers you downloaded from the NVIDIA drivers?  (Note the nvidia-drivers-550 package is nvidia packages, but built properly for existing kernels)

See my answer here to understand what Thomas is trying to tell you.  In short Ubuntu's Kernel and header files are frozen.  Installing NVIDIA's available drivers AND NOT THE ONE IN THE REPOSITORY breaks the linkage between the frozen modules, frozen header files and frozen kernel.  The Closest you'll get is Method 3: Add the PPA. Also read the warning under method 4

This question is similar to: Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
